# Creating Clickable CGPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have a UIView that contains a 'pie' with irregular sized slices and I need them to be clickable regions. Through a lot of trial and error I wrote a method to produce the pie, but now I am at a loss for how to make these slices into regions. Currently this method returns void so I need to modify to return something, like a CGPath? I guess where I'm really confused is how to take what I have and put it into a CGPath and return it. Any suggestions? thanks!

```
-(void)addClickableRegion:(float)beginDegrees to:(float)endDegrees withContext:(CGContextRef)ctx withRadiusOf:(int)rad{
    int x = self.bounds.size.height / 2;
    int y = self.bounds.size.width / 2;

    float red     = (arc4random() % 255)/255.0;
    float green   = (arc4random() % 255)/255.0;
    float blue    = (arc4random() % 255)/255.0;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, rad, (beginDegrees) * M_PI/180.0, (endDegrees) * M_PI/180.0, 0);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, red, green, blue, 1.0);

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already creating paths, you're just creating them in the context rather than creating them and then adding them to the context. You don't need to do that. You can use `CGPathCreateMutable`, `CGPathAddArc` and `CGContextAddPath`.

You can also use `UIBezierPath`, either via `bezierPathWithCGPath:` or directly (and then get the `CGPath` from them).

And, once you have bezier paths, you can call `containsPoint:` on them to hit test touches.